# Samsung S6 not recognized by Win10

Tags: windows-10, usb, android

I ran into a problem connecting my phone (Samsung S6) to my laptop.  It used to work fine and I could debug apps with Android Studio but now Windows tells me the USB device is not recognized.  I've tried a number of things to no avail.  The back story is the phone stopped charging and I rebooted it to a Black Screen of Death.  The only way to get it working again was to wipe the phone's system cache and now Win 10 doesn't see it.  Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried:

Rebooting everything

Reinstalled the latest Samsung USB driver (1.7.43)

Turing off Nord VPN

Different ports and cables

Turing off Developer mode and USB debugging

Ran Windows update

Ensured the USB mode is MTP

Android studio knows there's a device connected but can't use it.

Comment: Does the phone charge properly (e.g. not slower than usually) when connected to a charger? A common problem of smartphones is that the USB port soldering points break so that the USB port has a lose connection to the mainboard of the phone so that power and/or data connections do not work properly.

Comment: It does charge slow.  Sometimes I get Fast Charging sometimes not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a driver issue.

Go to device mananger, uninstall the drivers completely, reboot the pc, and install the correct drivers from the samsung website.

Comment: That's what I thought too.  I tried the latest USB drivers from Samsung and even a previous version.  Even ran Windows update.  No luck.

Comment: I've had a similar problem once, the trick was to uninstall the drivers completely, reboot and then install the correct drivers. The reboot is crucial.

Comment: Uninstalled drivers from driver manager and programs/features.  Clean reboot.  Plugged phone in and nothing.  Not even the error message that its not recognized.  Installed the latest Samsung driver.  Nothing happens.

Comment: You need to uninstall the drivers from device manager, then reboot, then run the setup you downloaded and only then plugin the phone. If that doesn't work, then you don't have the right drivers.

Comment: Did that.  There's not any USB driver listed in driver manager.  The driver is direct from Samsung's download center.

Comment: That should work. If not, then download a different driver from samsung. Their drivers are picky, but all problems always have been resorted by getting the right driver and installing that.

Comment: Got it working.  It was a combo of things.  A new driver.  A bad cable that worked sometimes.  Most important the Developer Mode USB Debugging had to be turned off.   On is for debugging apps with Android Studio, when off it acts line a normal USB phone connection.

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working.

Comment: Unforunatly the problem is back.

Comment: This is very strange.  I just connected the phone via USB and Win10 Explorer can't open it but Win10 Photos can and did import all the images.   Perhaps I have some background process turned off?

Comment: Then you need to open your phone, swipe down and change the USB connection setting. Its now set as a photo media device.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same with my S6. After several hours changing drivers, factory resetting phone and rebooting computer, I changed the USB cable and all was fine.